# Nivo slider jQuery causing a mixed content error in IE 8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, nivo-slider

I have an issue where I'm using the Nivo jQuery slider on a HTTPS: site and its javascript seems to be throwing a mixed content error in IE 8.

I currently have a forum post up in the Dev7 Studios forum with no response yet.  And I've googled for a couple of days on the IE 8 mixed content error.

So far, I haven't found a clear fix except for one post where a guy stated that sometimes the "innerHTML" in a jquery file can cause the error.  But he didn't really list a clear fix.

Does anyone have any insight in to this? Any help or direction appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any `<iframe>` elements without "src" attributes? That can cause the problem.

Comment: No, no iframes used on the page.  Its actually sitting in a content editor webpart of a secure SharePoint 2010 site.  Using basic HTML for the div it sits in.  After lots of testing, the error only happens when the "jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" file is called and running.  If I unhook it, no error.

Comment: I also hooked up "HTTPWatch" and checked, no outgoing HTTP lines to the server..

Comment: This comment taken from another blog: "There is another reason for this that I just discovered. jQuery uses “innerHtml” for .remove(), .html(), .empty(), etc. “innerHtml” will cause a mixed content warning in IE. One quick fix is to hide the current content using $(elem).contents().css(“display”,”none”) then append new content."  But I have no idea what he means all after "hide the current content".. I need some clarification or an example of that..

Comment: I've never experienced such problems with "innerHTML" in IE, and I've been doing work with jQuery, Prototype, and various IE versions for a long time.

Comment: apologies.. that comment is probably incorrect then.

Comment: Hey it's cool. I guess you'd have "innerHTML" problems if you used it to add an `<iframe>` without a "src" attribute :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, and have traced it to a bug in IE8. The comments on this page led me to a solution:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/06/22/https-mixed-content-in-ie8.aspx

This MS dev says:

> Fascinating. This is a race condition.
>
> The debugger reports that the following is the URL that is triggering
>   the prompt:
>
> "about:/images/lightview/inner_slideshow_play.png"
>
> Of course, that URL doesn't actually exist in your markup.  It looks
>   like there's dynamic creation of an IFRAME and injection of content
>   into that frame. The default URL for an empty frame is about:blank,
>   which leads to the prompt.
>
> As a workaround, using an absolute URL would probably work, or by
>   initializing the IFRAME with a the SRC of a blank page on your server
>   (this should also fix the Mixed Content problem with IE6).

Normal browsers don't have a problem with URLs for dynamic content that aren't fully qualified, protocol and all. But IE8 *sometimes* drops the ball and instead of putting in the protocol and host, it puts in "about:" in front of your path, and fails to trust that in a https context.

I edited nivoslider to qualify the URLs of all the images it draws dynamically. Further development would be needed to allow use of query strings in image URLs.

Here's my [edited source](http://pastebin.com/znhGMhjh).

Comment: Awesome Alex!  Let me know if you have a snippet that involves a fix,  I would love to see it.  We have removed the Nivo for now but I'd love to put it back up.

Comment: It's starting to look to me like a jquery bug that is exacerbated by the frequent calls from nivoslider... still working on it.

Comment: Makes total sense, as you don't see the error until a ways into the cycles of the slider.  I think I had the right idea but not the experience to develop a fix.  Good luck!

Comment: Before I tell you that I have it fixed, I will say that I think using fully qualified URLs for the slider images in your HTML source should also correct this problem. It's not so easy for me to pre-qualify URLs because the pages I'm working on are served from multiple vhosts, but the javascript should still be able to handle relative URLs, so I prefer to fix that.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to code that fixes the problem. I also have a minified version: [jquery.nivo.slider.pack_eah.js](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45963527/jquery.nivo.slider.pack_eah.js)

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for sharing this, now if I can get half of my clients to get off of IE 7, I'll almost have this entire problem solved.  Thanks again!

Comment: Correcting client behavior is an entirely different kind of problem. The solution: adjust your expectations to include their bad behavior.

If my code worked for you I'd like to know, and you can also mark my answer as "accepted." (hint, hint)

Comment: Yep, sorry about that.  Since we too Nivo down I will get to rebuild that particular situation and test it out next week.  I'll post back here.

Comment: So, I fixed the IE 7 thing by moving the pauseTime: 9000, to the bottom of the list and removing the comma from the end of it.  Fully qualifying the URLs worked perfectly Alex, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue.  In the header section I changed the src from `http://"mysite"/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js` to just `/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js` and worked.

Comment: Might want to find some current unanswered questions for that score motel1, this is answered and 3 years old